# Единственное или множественное число существительных

Tags: грамматика, единственное-множественное-число

Верно ли множественное число слова **стиль** во фразах: "Ваза прекрасно подходит для интерьеров в классическом и современном стилях", "...сочетает в себе классический и современный стили"?
И допускается ли единственное число?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, первая фраза составлена неудачно, в ней классический и современный стиль перечислены "на одном дыхании" как явления одного ряда, а следовало бы подчеркнуть их противоположность.  Кроме того, в данном предложении допущена неоднозначность: то ли "подходит в классическом стиле", то ли "для интерьеров в классическом стиле".

Мой вариант:

**Ваза прекрасно подходит для интерьеров как классического, так и  современного стиля.**

Касательно второй фразы, для понимания вопроса обратимся к Розенталю: §[194. Два определения при одном существительном](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04).

Я думаю, в данном случае подходит следующее положение:

> 1.Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится в форме единственного числа: ... 4)если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в правой и левой руке (половине, стороне и т.п.); оперное и балетное искусство; промышленный и аграрный переворот; учащиеся среднего и старшего школьного возраста; программы для восьмилетней и средней школы (как системы образования); в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языке; глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида (действительного и страдательного залога, настоящего и прошедшего времени, изъявительного и сослагательного наклонения, первого и второго спряжения и т.п.); существительные мужского, женского и среднего рода (первого и второго склонения, единственного и множественного числа); местоимения первого и второго лица; вирусный и простой грипп; головной и спинной мозг; война Алой и Белой розы.
>   Ср. также: Город был открыт для ветров с северной и восточной стороны.

**Ваза прекрасно сочетает в себе классический и современный стиль.**

Comment: Можно составить ещё одним образом, ёмче: "Ваза прекрасно подходит для интерьеров и классического, и современного стилей"